# Accessing inside precomposed layer with ExtendScript

Tags: javascript, adobe, composition, extendscript, after-effects

I am very new to extendScript. I have an After Effects project and I am trying to access an item in my composition then go to inside it to select one layer inside it. So it goes like: I have 5 layers in my composition and inside 3rd item, when I double click, there are some more layers. I want to achieve one of these inner layers.

```
var layerName = app.project.item(1).layer(4);
alert(layerName.name);
```

Using this, I can access the precomposed item's name in the main composition. Now I want to access inside it, just like when we double click in after effects. So that I can achieve a layer inside it.

What is the way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

you can access the layers of your precomp the same way you access the layers of your maincomp. let's say you want to access the first layer of your precomp, and your precomp is named "precomp". You would target

precomp.layer(1)

in order to do this, of course, you would probably want to identify your precomp and store it as a var, a la

```
var proj = app.project;
var target;

for (var i = 1; i <= proj.numItems; i++){
    if (proj.item(i) instanceOf CompItem && proj.item(i).name === 
    "precomp"){
        target = proj.item(i);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "achieve a layer inside it".
If a layer is a precomp, you can access its source (a CompItem) and open it in a viewer by script using comp.openInViewer(). 
The following lines will run through all the layers in the comp and open the precomp ones in a viewer.

```
for (i=1; i<=myComp.numLayers; i++){
    layer = myComp.layer(i);
    if (layer.source instanceof CompItem) layer.source.openInViewer();
    }
```